# Bootstrap 3 customized multilevel menu not working on smaller resolution

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu, responsive-design

I'm using Bootstrap 3 to create an HTML template to we used with a custom CMS.
You can find a demo HTML page here:
http://clienti.stefanoginella.com/loreal/pagina-prodotto.html

I've created a multilevel custom submenu (click on PRODOTTI and you will see it) using this "hack" http://www.bootply.com/92442 and YAMM http://geedmo.github.io/yamm/

There is some custom JS to make it work here http://clienti.stefanoginella.com/loreal/js/loreal.js
from line 71, the last part.

When in "desktop" mode it works perfectly.
But if you scale down the browser, when the menu collapse to the mobile version, it doesn't work anymore.

What I've tried is this (and none worked as a solution)

- deleting one of the two navbar
- deleting the YAMM css
- deleting the custom JS

the collapsed menu is still not working.
It opens and suddently automatically closes after a fraction of a second.

Do you have any idea about why this is happening and how to solve it?

Thanks a lot

*Stefano*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 166 in loreal.css is causing the issue - if you comment it out using web inspector the menu show / hides correctly.

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse { display:none !important; }
```

If you want the mobile navigation to kick in earlier you need to find the right media query in the bootstrap css and adjust it width values, or copy out all the bits you need and put it into your own css (it looks like you've attempted this, but not quite got it all!).

Comment: thanks, that solved the main problem! and yes, I was trying to enable the collapsed menu earlier (at 1199px, because the menu has a lot of items), I'll try to find a better solution to do this.